# Objectify async: at what point RPC call is made?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Quite often I want to make two or more independent queries to fetch entities from Datastore. But I'm not sure if they are really parallel. For example:

```
loadResult1 = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Foo.class, 1));
loadResult2 = ofy().load().key(Key.create(Bar.class, 1));

loadResult1.now();
loadResult2.now();
```

Is there any benefit of arranging the code like this?

Same goes for search queries

```
iterable1 = ofy().load().type(Foo.class).iterable();
iterable2 = ofy().load().type(Bar.class).iterable();

iterable1.hasNext();
iterable2.hasNext();
```

Will the `iterable2` load in parallel with iterable1?

Side question: is `.iterable()` in this regard any different from `.list()`?

I tried to debug the code, but it doesn't look like the call is made until call to `.now()`, or first call to `.next()/.hasNext()` in. Is it really so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - until you materialize a result, the queries proceed asynchronously in parallel.

Comment: But when the RPC call is made? After call to `.key()`, or when I call `.now()`? In other words, if between .key() and .now() there's some UrlFetch call, will they be parallel?

Comment: The RPC starts with key() and the result is materialized with now()